# Disabling minutes in certain hours in MUI time picker, reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, timepicker

Is it possible in MUI to disable some minutes in certain time in MUI time picker?
for example, I want to disable minute 30 in hour 5 only.
The user should not be able to select the time 5:30,
but should be able to select 30th minute of rest of the hours like 3:30, 4:30 ...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your `onChange()` handler is like but you may be able to utilize a **very** simple regex given how specific your use-case is.

For example;

```
const [date, setDate] = useState('');

const onChange = value => {
   const regex = new RegExp('5:30');
   
   if (!regex.test(value)) setDate(value);
}

return <DateTimePicker onChange={onChange} value={date} />;
```

Comment: This will help in not storing the value '5:30' in date, I need to disable it in the clock with the shouldDisableTime  property of <TimePicker/> component